# C++: Incrementing an int variable with sizeof() operator inside a for loop only works once?

Tags: c++

I was trying to increment my int variable using the sizeof() operator inside a for loop which runs for two iterations.

I am running this code on Turbo compiler.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main(){

    int *p, c = 0;

    p = new int[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        c = c + sizeof(p + i);

    cout<<c;

    getch();
}
```

i expected the output to be 8 since in the first iteration it will store 4 in c and in the second iteration it will just double up but surprisingly the output is only 4 and i cant figure out why. i tried printing inside the for loop as well and i it shows it indeed runs twice not once.

Comment: *" i tried printing inside the for loop as well and i it shows it indeed runs twice not once"* - but apparently decided to leave that version of the code *out* ? What was actually printed in that loop that iterated twice, *on each iteration*? Related, try a tool chain made in the last decade or so.

Comment: A little `cout << sizeof(p+i);` would go a long way. When the result is surprising, verify your assumptions.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you think the first iteration will store 4 in `c`? If we knew your reasoning, we could explain where it goes awry.

Comment: It's frightening how many still use Turbo C++ these days.

Comment: For the next time, always post *working code* with which one can easily reproduce the error. `void main` is not correct, and the file `iostream` does not have an extension. Other than that, you should state what you want first. You do realize that you do not dereference your pointer? Your code looks like you are trying to iterate over the content of it, but you don't do that.

Comment: @Aziuth i am sorry if this code didn't work for you but i tried it first before putting it here and it is a working code (for my given environment).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz because in 16 bit compilers int takes 2 bytes. i completely missed that pointer arithmetic point so i mistakenly thought it would add 2 + 2 to c which are the sizes of int* and int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`p + i` is a pointer arithmetic expression. Its type in your case is `int*`. So `sizeof(p + i)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`.

So the output you observe is consistent with `sizeof(int*)` being 2, which I don't believe, although you could check that trivially.

It wouldn't surprise me if your old compiler was buggy, and is evaluating the expression as `sizeof(int)`. Turbo C++ is long gone.

Comment: *"... which I don't believe." - believe it. He's using small-memory model Turbo C++ running on 16 bit DOS, near-pointers are 16 bit (seriously). Amazingly, I used that thing too... in my grad school.... in 1991 (also seriously).

Comment: Those were the days. I also remember that Borland C++ 2.0 or so was one of my first "serious" C++ environments :) It must have been around 1989 or so when I used Turbo C++. Yet, a while ago, I learned here on SO, that many Indian schools still use such old tools for their courses. Amazing, since they cannot really save money compared to installing FreeBSD or *cough* Linux.

Comment: Don't laugh, so did the Space Program. The Borland DOS version was a pre-windows juggernaut that ran really well on 286 machines. You just had to like blue backgrounds with yellow text `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I mostly used QEdit back then. It was the bang - and industry standard, too! Wordstar compatible :)

Comment: It's been a wild ride to think that the first part of my career where the primary office tools were the typewriter with carbon-paper for duplicates and documents actually mailed (with a stamp) which continued from the late 80's throughout the 90's. Oh what a tangled web we have woven...

Comment: oh so this is why it printed 4 not 8, i completely missed that pointer arithmetic point. thank you! apart from this, alot of you are talking about newer compilers, would the output be any different if this was compiled on a modern compiler? (apart from varying size of int) i tried on gcc and it gave me 16.

Comment: @MohitSaxena — the difference wouldn’t be because of the size of `int`, but of `int*`.